# Delete specific rows after filling information

Tags: r, tidyverse

I need to fill up information about clients, and in order to avoid duplicated information, I need to delete where the information came from. My dataset looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(datea = c(NA,"202105",NA,NA,"202106",NA,NA,"202110",NA),
                  client_id = c("aaa","aaa","bbb","ccc","ccc","ddd","eee","eee","eee"),
                  dateb = c("202105",NA,"202107","202106",NA,"202110","202107",NA,"202107"),
                  qt_prod1 = c(10,NA,30,2,NA,11,14,NA,145),
                  qt_prod2 = c(12,NA,433,221,NA,312,312,NA,121))

> dat
   datea client_id  dateb qt_prod1 qt_prod2
1   <NA>       aaa 202105       10       12
2 202105       aaa   <NA>       NA       NA
3   <NA>       bbb 202107       30      433
4   <NA>       ccc 202106        2      221
5 202106       ccc   <NA>       NA       NA
6   <NA>       ddd 202110       11      312
7   <NA>       eee 202107       14      312
8 202110       eee   <NA>       NA       NA
9   <NA>       eee 202107      145      121
```

What I want is kind of merge the dataset in order to have all the information in one row, but by client. I don't want client bbb to have it's information filled with client aaa data. My desired output would be:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(datea = c("202105",NA,"202106",NA,"202110",NA),
                  client_id = c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","eee"),
                  dateb = c("202105","202107","202106","202110","202107","202107"),
                  qt_prod1 = c(10,30,2,11,14,145),
                  qt_prod2 = c(12,433,221,312,312,121))

> dat2
   datea client_id  dateb qt_prod1 qt_prod2
1 202105       aaa 202105       10       12
2   <NA>       bbb 202107       30      433
3 202106       ccc 202106        2      221
4   <NA>       ddd 202110       11      312
5 202110       eee 202107       14      312
6   <NA>       eee 202107      145      121
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(client_id) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ sort(., na.last = TRUE))) %>%
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(cur_data())) > 0) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   datea  client_id dateb  qt_prod1 qt_prod2
#   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 202105 aaa       202105       10       12
# 2 NA     bbb       202107       30      433
# 3 202106 ccc       202106        2      221
# 4 NA     ddd       202110       11      312
# 5 202110 eee       202107       14      121
# 6 NA     eee       202107      145      312
```

I should add that this operation is not "clean": data across a row is not preserved together, so a common presumption about frames where a row is an observation is not preserved. This might be intentional.

Comment: Thanks! Is intentional, the presumption is not preserved. However, in your solution, data from eee client is not correct, specifically variables qt_prod1 and qt_prod2, which are inverted. Is there a way to fix this?