# Align different observations by variable id columns to eliminate NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have an R data frame similar to this format:

```
df<-data.frame(

Fruit=c("Apples","Apples","Apples","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Cherries","Cherries","Cherries"),
Order=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B"),
Producer_ID=c("V","V","V","W","W","W","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z"),
x1=c(   0.7975,NA,NA,0.570975,NA,NA,0.43374375,NA,NA,0.610624,NA,NA,0.6975,NA,NA),
y1=c(   200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA),
x2=c(   NA,NA,0.82,NA,NA,0.51,NA,NA,0.415,NA,NA,0.542,NA,NA,0.62),
y2=c(   NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200),
x3=c(   NA,NA,0.82,NA,NA,0.505,NA,NA,0.4125,NA,NA,0.538,NA,NA,0.62),
y3=c(   NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200),
x4=c(   NA,0.82,NA,NA,NA,0.5,NA,NA,0.41,NA,NA,0.534,NA,NA,0.62),
y4=c(   NA,300,NA,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA, NA,200),
x5=c(   NA,0.82,NA,NA,NA,0.495,NA,NA,0.4075,NA,NA,0.53,NA,0.62,NA),
y5=c(   NA,300,NA,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,NA,200,NA,300,NA),
x6=c(   NA,0.82,NA,NA,0.49,NA,NA,0.405,NA,NA,0.52,NA,NA,0.62,NA),
y6=c(   NA, 300,NA,NA,300,NA,NA,300,NA,NA,300,NA,NA,300,NA)
)
```

Output:

```
> df
      Fruit Order Producer_ID        x1  y1    x2  y2     x3  y3    x4  y4     x5  y5    x6  y6
1    Apples     A           V 0.7975000 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
2    Apples     A           V        NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA 0.820 300 0.8200 300 0.820 300
3    Apples     A           V        NA  NA 0.820 200 0.8200 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
4   Bananas     B           W 0.5709750 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
5   Bananas     B           W        NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA 0.490 300
6   Bananas     B           W        NA  NA 0.510 200 0.5050 200 0.500 200 0.4950 200    NA  NA
7   Bananas     B           X 0.4337437 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
8   Bananas     B           X        NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA 0.405 300
9   Bananas     B           X        NA  NA 0.415 200 0.4125 200 0.410 200 0.4075 200    NA  NA
10  Bananas     B           Y 0.6106240 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
11  Bananas     B           Y        NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA 0.520 300
12  Bananas     B           Y        NA  NA 0.542 200 0.5380 200 0.534 200 0.5300 200    NA  NA
13 Cherries     B           Z 0.6975000 200    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA
14 Cherries     B           Z        NA  NA    NA  NA     NA  NA    NA  NA 0.6200 300 0.620 300
15 Cherries     B           Z        NA  NA 0.620 200 0.6200 200 0.620 200     NA  NA    NA  NA
```

For each combination of the identifier columns "Fruit", "Order", "Producer", there is precisely one non-NA value in each of the remaining columns. What I want to do is wrangle my data frame to eliminate the NA values, lining up the non-NA values with their identifiers, like this:

```
df_final<-data.frame(

Fruit=c("Apples","Bananas","Bananas","Bananas","Cherries"),
Order=c("A","B","B","B","B"),
Producer_ID=c("V","W","X","Y","Z"),
x1=c(0.7975,0.570975,0.43374375,0.610624,0.6975),
y1=c(200,200,200,200,200),
x2=c(0.82,0.51,0.415,0.542,0.62),
y2=c(200,200,200,200,200),
x3=c(0.82,0.505,0.4125,0.538,0.62),
y3=c(200,200,200,200,200),
x4=c(0.82,0.5,0.41,0.534,0.62),
y4=c(300,200,200,200,200),
x5=c(0.82,0.495,0.4075,0.53,0.62),
y5=c(300,200,200,200,300),
x6=c(0.82,0.49,0.405,0.526,0.62),
y6=c(300,300,300,300,300)
)
```

Final output:

```
> df_final
     Fruit Order Producer_ID        x1  y1    x2  y2     x3  y3    x4  y4     x5  y5    x6  y6
1   Apples     A           V 0.7975000 200 0.820 200 0.8200 200 0.820 300 0.8200 300 0.820 300
2  Bananas     B           W 0.5709750 200 0.510 200 0.5050 200 0.500 200 0.4950 200 0.490 300
3  Bananas     B           X 0.4337437 200 0.415 200 0.4125 200 0.410 200 0.4075 200 0.405 300
4  Bananas     B           Y 0.6106240 200 0.542 200 0.5380 200 0.534 200 0.5300 200 0.526 300
5 Cherries     B           Z 0.6975000 200 0.620 200 0.6200 200 0.620 200 0.6200 300 0.620 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only one value in each column for a group (`Fruit`, `Order` and `Producer_ID`) you can take `sum`(or `max`) of each column ignoring the `NA` values.

In base R with `aggregate` -

```
aggregate(.~Fruit+Order+Producer_ID, df, sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)

#    Fruit Order Producer_ID        x1  y1    x2  y2     x3  y3    x4  y4     x5  y5    x6  y6
#1   Apples     A           V 0.7975000 200 0.820 200 0.8200 200 0.820 300 0.8200 300 0.820 300
#2  Bananas     B           W 0.5709750 200 0.510 200 0.5050 200 0.500 200 0.4950 200 0.490 300
#3  Bananas     B           X 0.4337437 200 0.415 200 0.4125 200 0.410 200 0.4075 200 0.405 300
#4  Bananas     B           Y 0.6106240 200 0.542 200 0.5380 200 0.534 200 0.5300 200 0.520 300
#5 Cherries     B           Z 0.6975000 200 0.620 200 0.6200 200 0.620 200 0.6200 300 0.620 300
```

Or using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Fruit, Order ,Producer_ID) %>%
  summarise(across(x1:y6, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Ronak Shah 's `sum`, here is an optional method with `sort` to aggegate all non NA values in the same row (inspired by
@r2evans https://stackoverflow.com/a/70772167/7522764)

```
df |>
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ sort(., na.last = TRUE))) |>
    na.omit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use `tidyr` to reshape to long format, get rid of NAs and finally reshape back to wide format.

Note: As an intermediate step I use `arrange(gsub("^.*?(\\d)$", "\\1", name))` to rearrange the data so that the columns in the wide df are ordered in your desired order.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Fruit, Order, Producer_ID)) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  arrange(gsub("^.*?(\\d)$", "\\1", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")
#> # A tibble: 5 × 15
#>   Fruit  Order Producer_ID    x1    y1    x2    y2    x3    y3    x4    y4    x5
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Apples A     V           0.798   200 0.82    200 0.82    200 0.82    300 0.82 
#> 2 Banan… B     W           0.571   200 0.51    200 0.505   200 0.5     200 0.495
#> 3 Banan… B     X           0.434   200 0.415   200 0.412   200 0.41    200 0.408
#> 4 Banan… B     Y           0.611   200 0.542   200 0.538   200 0.534   200 0.53 
#> 5 Cherr… B     Z           0.698   200 0.62    200 0.62    200 0.62    200 0.62 
#> # … with 3 more variables: y5 <dbl>, x6 <dbl>, y6 <dbl>
```